# if doesn't support the nested "equals" element in ant build file

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Below is my code. We are using Ant verison 1.9.11 and tried with the ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar and ant-contrib-1.0b2.jar.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

<target name=abc>
<if>
  <equals arg1="${xyz}" arg2="true"/>
  <then>
    <replace file="src/com/xyz.java" token="DEBUG = false;" value="DEBUG = true;" />
  </then>
  <else>
    <echo message="${xyz} is not enabled "/>
  </else>           
</if>   
</target>
```

I've also tried using the full path of ant contrib like below, but am still getting the same errors.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
<classpath>
  <pathelement location="/opt/apache-ant-1.9.11/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

It would be really appreciate help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [antcontrib site](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html), the taskdef using antcontrib.properties is for Ant version 1.5 *only*, so you need to use the antlib.xml taskdef instead. And you will need the nested classpath you tried, so likely in your case you need something like:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/opt/apache-ant-1.9.11/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</tsakdef>
```

Comment: thanks for taking time on this to post your answer. i have tried changing the ant as requested but still gettig the same errors.

Comment: It works for me with your if task!  Try running ant -v and inspect the output for issues.